# Programming Language Idea: Avoiding vtable lookups

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, programming-languages, compiler-optimization, vtable

I have been toying with an idea for a programming language for a while now: It would essentially be C++ and Java-like in syntax, meant for systems programming (or really any programming that requires high-performance), but with, in my opinion, a more enjoyable syntax than C++. I was thinking about how I would handle virtual methods in hierarchical class structures (my language would not include multiple inheritance), and ways of avoiding vtable lookups. My question is twofold:

1. To my understanding, the reason vtable lookups are such a performance-hit (in time-critical scenarios like game-development, at least), is because it requires deferencing the objects vtable pointer, and this vtable is generally a cache-miss. Is this correct, or am I missing some part of the problem?
2. My idea for a partial solution is this: If the compiler can determine an object's type completely (ie. it cannot be a type derived from the type it thinks it is), and this object is passed to a function as an argument whose type is a superclass of the object's type, then the location of the virtual method called in the function can be passed as a sort of "hidden" argument, which is added at compile-time. Perhaps an example would help:

Consider the following pseudo-code for a class hierarchy:

```
class Animal {
    public void talk() { /* Generic animal noise... */ }
    // ...
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    public void talk() { /* Override of Animal::talk(). */ }
    // ...
}

void main() {
    Dog d = new Dog();
    doSomethingWithAnimal(d);
}

void doSomethingWithAnimal(Animal a) {
    // ...
    a.talk();
    // ....
}
```

Keep in mind that this is pseudocode, not C++ or Java or similar. Also, assume that the Animal argument is implicitly passed by reference, not value. Because the compiler can see that `d` is definitely of type `Dog`, it could translate the `doSomethingWithAnimal` definition into something like this:

```
void doSomethingWithAnimal(Animal a, methodptr talk = NULL) {
    // ...
    if ( talk != NULL ) {
        talk(a);
    } else {
        a.talk();
    }
    // ...
}
```

Then `main` would look be translated by the compiler to something like this:

```
void main() {
    Dog d = new Dog();
    doSomethingWithAnimal(d, Dog::talk);
}
```

Obviously this wouldn't completely eradicate the need for a vtable, and one would probably still need to be provided for the cases when the objects exact type cannot be determined, but what are your thoughts on this as a performance optimization? I plan on using registers to pass arguments whenever possible, and even if the arguments had to spill onto the stack, it is more likely that the methodptr argument on the stack will be a cache-hit than the vtable values, right? Any and all thoughts are much appreciated.

Comment: this technique is already implemented in most all production c++ compilers and goes by the name of "devirtualization".

Comment: You might want to revisit the premise that virtual dispatch is slow until you measure it. Also note that `if` (branches) have a different impact in performance, which might be even larger than the impact of the virtual dispatch. When the compiler *knows* the object type at compile time, it won't use dynamic dispatch anyway, but in your proposal the functions would have to take a number of hidden parameter (another cost) for each of the possible functions that it needs. You might end up incurring a larger cost than you are trying to remove...

Comment: @KyleLutz - can it handle the case described by Zach though? I thought that when compiling `doSomethingWithAnimal` as a compilation unit, the compiler cannot infer the static type of `a` and so cannot do anything about the problem at hand.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas True, though the branch can be eliminated (at the cost of code bloat) by generating an overload.

Comment: @delnan: Yes, you can avoid the `if` by providing suitable overloads, but how many will you need? How many functions can be called on the argument? How many arguments do you want to pass? Or will you have to see the definition of the function to infer the needs and pass only those needed? --uhm... don't you get exactly that when the compiler inlines?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas That's another problem, yes. And yes, inlining can solve this to a degree, but requires either LTO or giving up separate compilation -- not to mention that inlining *also* adds code bloat.

Comment: furthermore, `doSomethingWithAnimal()` is flawed in that it accepts `Animal a` by value and thus `Animal::talk()` will always be called due to type-slicing. this can be fixed by changing the signature to `void doSomethingWithAnimal(Animal &a, methodptr talk = NULL)`.

Comment: @delnan: The question is whether the set of questions in my last comment can be answered without doing exactly what compilers do today. In an oversimplified example in the question there is a pointer to the final overrider for the single member function, but in real code there would be multiple such members. Passing all them as arguments would be more costly than the virtual dispatch, knowing which ones to pass would be hard in a separate compilation model and it would push the implementation of the function into the interface (at least into the interface that the compiler sees)

Comment: Can I be the annoying one? `Dog d = new Dog();` <-- `new Dog()` is a `Dog*`.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain, KyleLutz: OP says he's thinking about a new language and that his code is pseudocode. His idea may well be to implement java-like syntax/semantics for these things, so your comments about `*` and type slicing may not apply.

Comment: I couldn't agree more with @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Unless you have very solid *hard evidence* that virtual dispatch is a critical performance bottleneck, going all the way to design and implement a *new language* is one of the most extreme reactions I've seen yet.

Comment: Just to clear up some confusion, my examples are in pseudocode, not C++, as @us2012 mentioned, and the `Animal` (or `Dog`) argument is implicitly passed by reference, not value. I will update the question to reflect that better. Also, as far as actual measurements of virtual dispatch performance, I started thinking about this after reading a code review of the Doom3 source, which mentions a few techniques the developers used to avoid vtable lookups. From this I assumed that id software had run into performance issues, but I have not seen actual measurements.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Re Q1:** Cache utilization is only one part of the "problem" with virtual calls actually. The whole point of `virtual` functions, and late binding in general, is that the call site may call any implementation without changes. This mandates some indirection:

- Indirection implies space and/or time overhead to resolve the indirection.
- No matter how you do the indirection, and indirect call can only be as fast as a static call if the CPU has a good branch predictor *and* the call site is monomorphic (i.e., only one implementation is ever called). And I'm not even sure if a perfectly-predicted branch is as fast as a static branch on all hardware developers care about.
- Not knowing the called function at compile time also inhibits optimization based on knowing the called function (inlining, but also loop invariant code motion and possibly more).

Your approach doesn't change that, and hence leaves most of the performance problems in place: It still wastes some time and space (only on additional arguments and branches, rather than vtable lookups), it doesn't permit inlining or other optimizations, and it doesn't remove indirect calls.

**Re 2:** It's kind of an interprocedural spin on devirtualization, which C++ compilers already do to some degree (locally, with limitations as described by @us2012 in the comments). There are a few "minor" problems with it, but it may be worth it *if* applied selectively. Otherwise, you generate a lot more code, pass a *lot* of additional arguments, do a *lot* of extra branches, and only gain very little or even a net loss.

I assume the main issue is that it doesn't solve most of the performance issues described above. Generating specialized functions (rather than one generic body) for subclasses, and other variations of the same theme, *may* help with that. But that generates additional code that has to justify itself with performance gains, and the general consensus is that such aggressive optimizations aren't worth it for most code even in performance-critial programs.

In particular, virtual call overhead only matters in benchmarks of that very same feature, or if you already optimized the ever-loving hell out of everything else and would need a huge lot of tiny indirect calls (an example from game development: Several virtual method calls per geometrical object for drawing or frustum culling). In most code, the virtual calls don't matter, or at least not enough to warrant further optimization attempts. In addition, this is only relevant for AOT compilers, as JIT compilers have other ways of dealing with these problems. Look up polymorphic inline caches, and note that tracing JIT compilers can trivially inline *all* calls, virtual or not.

In summary: vtables are already a fast and general way to implement virtual functions (if they *can* be used, which is the case here). It's unlikely you're be able to improve much on them, let alone notice the improvement, except perhaps in some rare cases. If you want to try it though, you could try writing an LLVM pass that does something like this (though you'd have to work on a lower level of abstraction).